# PHP to Javascript array trouble

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

so I have this code:

```
var loc = new Array();
        <?php foreach($loc as $key => $val) { ?>
            loc.push('<?php print_r($val); ?>');
        <?php } ?>
```

The problem is is that it's only showing one value and not more than one, like it should. This is the php array code:

```
$loc = array($lat, $long);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) is ***only*** for debugging.  It's not for anything else.

Comment: Why are you using `print_r()`? It's only used to display a formatted version of your array and is ***not*** to be used for transferring data from client <-> server. Use JSON format instead, as shown in [Niet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074343/) below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var loc = <?php echo json_encode($loc); ?>;
```

You should not use `print_r`. Let me quote the [documentation](http://php.net/print-r):

> `print_r` — Prints **human-readable** information about a variable

Note the part I emphasised. "*human-readable*". Just because it looks vaguely like something JavaScript might understand, doesn't mean it is ;) [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode), on the other hand, is specifically designed to output JSON, which is a subset of the syntax JavaScript accepts for variables.

Comment: Ninja'd. +1 for being fast (and correct, at the same time).

Comment: I think it'd be better to have a short explanation of why the given code doesn't work :)